# RichTextBox - highlight entire selected line

Tags: c#, richtextbox

So I can't find anything regarding what I'm asking, I have looked as much as I can and I can't find anything.

What I'm developing is a Java IDE in C# and .NET, and I was wondering if I can get the RichTextBox to select and highlight the whole line when, for example, the user holds `Shift` and press down a bunch of times, it highlights the entire lines as you do it, in IDEs like Eclipse, Intellij, etc.

Comment: It does that anyway, without code. (I'm assuming WinForms?) Or perhaps you mean that, as soon as you start, it highlights to the beginning of the current line, and then the end of the next line(s)? That would require code, and effort, but is it necessary?

Comment: Please also note the difference between selecting and highlighting!

Comment: @Andy G - It's just for aesthetics

Comment: @TaW - I'm talking about when you hold shift and press down in IDEs like eclipse, it highlights the entire line you are on. I'm trying to get that effect. and like I said above, it's just for aesthetics, because I think it looks visually nice to see the whole line get selected.

Comment: To confirm: That's *selecting*, as it changes the selection. (That said, I'm not a [tag:c#] developer so I don't know the *answer*...)